# clear value for all input decendants of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, coffeescript

I have an HTML document. There is a particular div that user needs to be able to copy - so when the user clicks a certain link, a copy of this div will be appended to the document.  This div contains a form with populated inputs.  I don't want the copy to include the input values.  I am using coffeescript and jquery.  So - I need a coffescript which will create a copy of an element,  strip all values from any input elements, and append this copy to the document when asked to do so.  Here is my disfunctional attempt:

```
template = $('<div></div>')
template.addClass('proposal-unit')

stripText = ->
  this.val("") 

addUnit = ->
  $('#proposal-properties').append(template)
  $('.delete-row').on("click", deleteUnit)

deleteUnit = ->
  $(this).closest('.proposal-unit').remove()

reload = ->
  $('#add-row').on("click", addUnit)
  $('.delete-row').on("click", deleteUnit)
  template.html($('.proposal-unit').first().html())
  template.find('input').each stripText

$(document).on('page:load', reload)

$ ->
  reload()
```

Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide a jsfiddle? it seems you are clearing the value of the div, which shouldn't have a value anyway. You should be clearing the values of the form fields.

Comment: `template.find('input').val('')` should have cleared the inputs on `template`.